# I keep getting "Acces denied" notification when I use some cmd commands,although I'm in Administrator Mode

Tags: command-line, windows-10, command-prompt

I start recently to learn the command-prompt commands.I started with some basic commands:***dir,cd,mkdir and move***.I tried to move a directory from c:/users/user/documents/ called P1.I wanted to move the respective directory(P1)in d:(root directory).But I keep recevieng the "Acces denied" notification, although I'm using the cmd in Administrator mode. There're no relevant tutorials on youtube or topics discussing a solution for this.Can someone help me with that ? I don't what to use other scripts for solving my problem,I need a solution that will solve these problem on any windows machine(starting from 7) if it's needed. I also disabled UAC, but had no effect.

Comment: Since your question is not actually about programming, you may get better response on [Super user](http://superuser.com). When you move your question over there, please edit to show the actual command you are using.

Comment: Please also consult the Help Center for information on [what is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)